# Make java supplier return a value using side effect

Tags: java, spring-boot, lambda, functional-programming, supplier

I have a java suppler that returns a `Student` pojo like so:

```
    @Bean
    public Supplier<Date> studentSupplier() {
        return () -> new Student();
    }
```

Now I want to make this supplier returns a `Student` pojo after an entry is created using api..something like so

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/student",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Student> createStudent() {
        Student student = service.createStudent();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(student);
    }


    @Bean
    public Supplier<Student> studentSupplier() {
        return () -> {
        // How do I make this supplier return the Student pojo
        // created in above controller call? 
        };
    }
```

Please note I can't change the signature (for exmaple change `Supplier` to a `Function`).. The supplier interface is plugged into an external system that I can't control

Comment: Is there only a single student in service? If yes, look for a method in `service` to retrieve the unique user

Comment: What's wrong with: `return () -> service.createStudent()`?

Comment: two flows are independent of each other.. student can only be created using the api

Comment: Can you add more details about the expectation of `createStudent` and `studentSupplier`? I assume `createStudent` will be called multiple times. If so, what should `studentSupplier` return when invoked? Should it return the students in the order created by `createStudent`? or should it return the last created student? What should it return if students are not yet created? What are the consistency requirements?